# Unable to display my response in Label and Image view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uilabel

I am getting response from my server like

```
"account_details" =     (
                {
            "
        }
    );
    response = yes;
```

i created for object for all my keywords which i need to access.

like

```
 NSString *companyname = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"account_details"]valueForKey:@"company_name"];
                                                       NSLog(@" company_name  is:%@",companyname);
```

and

```
NSString *userlogo=
                                                               [[dictionary valueForKey:@"account_details"]valueForKey:@"user_logo"];

                                                               NSLog(@"user_logo is :%@",user logo);
```

for this code i am getting response like:

[3397:1510814]  company_name  is:(
        naveen
    user_logo is :(
       /~/uploads/userphotos/.png"

i try to display that data and image in my app. but i am not succeed.

please help me guy's.

Thank you.

Comment: account_details is array of dictionary....not Dictionary

Comment: I am using for  displaying the data in label is                                         lb1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",companyname]; for in mu table it displaying       (     " means its shows open bracket"

Comment: You should try and a shot at implementing it and post where you get stuck. Your question is too broad. To get you on the way you need to create an NSImage with contents of url and then add it to the NSImageView. For the label this will be simply an outlet to an NSTextField. For accessing objects in your NSDictionaries `array[@"key"][@"anotherKey"]` is nice and readable. Kudos for using Objective-C.

Comment: PS: Divide and conquer!

Comment: thank you @sidneydobber. next time will minimise stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your  dictionary value for key account_details is an array so write it as follow

```
[[[dictionary valueForKey:@"account_details"]objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"company_name"];
```

and if it can be null then please put condition `if([[dictionary valueForKey:@"account_details"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && [[dictionary valueForKey:@"account_details"] count] > 0)` and write your code

Comment: how to display my image

Comment: `imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [[[dictionary valueForKey:@"account_details"]objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"user_logo"]]]];`

Comment: also you can use third party library like "SDWebImage" to display image from URL. it will set Image in background thread because if you use NSData dataWithContentsOfURL it will freeze your application during downloading image